# Webview with JavaScript interface

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I am building a mobile application which should be interacted from java to javascript.

I found the solution in this link [Passing an array of values from Android Activity to JavaScript in a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331004/passing-an-array-of-values-from-android-activity-to-javascript-in-a-webview?rq=1). But my problem is when i declare webview its showing error like

> None of the methods in the added interface have been annotated with
>   @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface; they will not be visible in API
>   17

What should I do to remove this error? I am very new to this core java. Please suggest me and help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

From the docs:

**Caution**: If you've set your targetSdkVersion to 17 or higher, you must add the @JavascriptInterface annotation to any method that you want available your web page code (the method must also be public). If you do not provide the annotation, then the method will not accessible by your web page when running on Android 4.2 or higher.

Please take a look here http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: Thanks. I missed 'public' !